# AVL tree with balance factor equal to depth

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, avl-tree

If you were to define an altered AVL tree where the balance factor (the difference between the height of the left and right subtree) of a node must be less than or equal to the depth of the node (in absolute value), would it be balanced (h is in O(log n))? How would you prove so?

Comment: You'll have to allow the balance factor to be one more than the depth, or you cannot even create a tree with 2 nodes, nor with 4, ...Etc

Comment: This question seems unrelated to programming, and would be a better fit for [computer science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbinary-trees%5D+avl), or even [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btrees%5D+avl).